# WebDriverManager fetching outdated chrome driver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-manager, webdrivermanager-python

My WebDriverManager appears to be attempting to fetch a chromedriver that is outdated, and I am not sure why. I've checked already that my Chrome is up to date. (107.0.5304.107 as of day of writing)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

returns this error:

```
raise ValueError(f"There is no such driver by url {resp.url}")
ValueError: There is no such driver by url https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/54.0.2840/chromedriver_win32.zip
```

I've also checked the history of chrome drivers and all of them start from 70+ onwards, yet it appears I am trying to fetch one from version 54?

Appreciate any help!

Comment: you can download chrome driver https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads. and the set the path `webdriver.Chrome("path")`

Comment: Try updating your webdriver manager and selenium to make sure they're up to date. There has been some renaming of binaries going on.

Comment: You can also specify a specific version with `webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager(version='106.0.5249.61').install()))`